# Discovering and saving url as a string in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I am making request using as3 on graph api.

For example I am requesting this url.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/100001217469714/picture
```

But I am redirected to this url.

```
http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/274715_100001217469714_1254733069_q.jpg
```

I would like to get this redirected url to my AS3 code as string.
How should I do this?

I am doing it because I am loading profile pictures from Facebook to my game. But I have to discover if user uploaded photo or have facebook predefined photo.

```
var url : String = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'+id+'/picture?width=100&height=100';
var urlRequestPicture : URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
urlRequestPicture.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;            
var loaderPicture : Loader = new Loader();
loaderPicture.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompletePicture);
loaderPicture.load(urlRequestPicture);

function onCompletePicture(e:Event){
    var bitmap:Bitmap = e.target.content;
    bitMapArray.push(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url property in target should give you the url of the image :

```
function onCompletePicture(e:Event){
    var bitmap:Bitmap = e.target.content;
    trace(e.target.url);
}
```